# Unexpected error occurs while populating android ListView with database in a Fragment class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to populate `ListView` from database, as I am using Navigation drawer so I need to use Fragment to show my View instead of Activity. Everything is fine but when I run my application it shows me a error that **column _id does not exits** but my query is **SELECT city_name, country_name, favorite FROM city;**. My database table is.

[image]

My Android application screen is:

[image]

When I click **All City** (position=3) I want to populate my List with city_name and country_name from my database. But It shows error **column _id does not exits** but did not use _id in my query and also my table contains _id. So why this error?

My Code section is given below:

selectItem() method from MyActivity.java Class, When I select All City position=3

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(MyFragment.ARG_OS, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle((navMenuTitles[position]));
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else if (position == 3) {

        AllCityListFragment myfragment = new AllCityListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, myfragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle((navMenuTitles[position]));
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java: This is working fine, In this question I require createdatabase(), opendatabase() and getResult() method getResult returns a Cursor.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String PACKAGE_NAME;

    private static String DB_PATH;

    private static String DB_NAME = "weatherbd.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        PACKAGE_NAME = myContext.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/databases/";
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor getResult(String sql) {

        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

        return c;
    }

}
```

AllListFragment.java Class to show populated list from database, Here error is coming from the query **SELECT city_name, country_name, favorite FROM city;**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AllCityListFragment extends Fragment {
    private CustomList customAdapter;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    ListView list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_city_layout, null);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(view.getContext());

        try {
            databaseHelper.createDataBase();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Database Created",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            databaseHelper.openDataBase();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Database Opened",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.citylist);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Cliked on item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    customAdapter = new CustomList(
                            view.getContext(),
                            databaseHelper
                                    .getResult("SELECT city_name, country_name, favorite FROM city;"));
                    list.setAdapter(customAdapter);

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

CustomList.java class extends CursorAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends CursorAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomList(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_city_list, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        cityName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("city_name")));

        TextView countryName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
        countryName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country_name")));

        CheckBox favoriteBox = (CheckBox) view
                .findViewById(R.id.favoriteCheckBox);
        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("favorite")) == 0) {
            favoriteBox.setSelected(false);
        } else {
            favoriteBox.setSelected(true);
        }

    }
}
```

LogCat:

[image]

I restarted my Eclipse IDE but still I have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor has to include the `_id` column, when used with `CursorAdapter`. Add the `_id` column to your query. From the documentation:

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The
>   Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.